# Compare string with data on a file

Tags: c++, string, file-handling

How can I take input from a user and compare it with data on a file?

`Myfile.txt` contains the following Data

```
Louise Ravel
Raven
Wings
Crosses and Bridges
Bjarne
```

In my Program

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>

   int main()
   {
       std::ifstream file("Myfile.txt");
       std::string name;
       std::cout<<"Enter the name to compare with the data: ";
       std::getline(std::cin,name);
       return 0;
   }
```

Now once the user enters the input, I want to compare the string entered with the data available in `MyFile.txt` and if a matching string is found then just simply print `"Match Found"`

I tried this one but it didn't work.

```
while(file>>name)
    {
        if(file==name)
        {
            cout<<"Match Found";
        }
    }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Stack overflow isn't a homework writing service.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to proceed about it? I've tried using `while(file>>name)
    {
        if(file==name)
        {
            cout<<"Match Found";
        }
    }` but it didn't work

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52926293/edit) your question to include that code. Did you try debugging?

Comment: I'm pretty much a beginner at programming so don't know anything about debugging

Comment: is it a good idea to learn about debugging at this point?

Comment: Learning to debug is far more important than learning to code, see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thanks I'll first learn debugging :) I'm self taught so I don't get much good advice. Really appreciate it ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is incorrect. You are reading your names from the file into the same variable as you read the user input from. You are also then comparing the file to the read name which will always return false.

Try:

```
std::string nameFromFile;
while(file>>nameFromFile)
{
    if(nameFromFile==name)
    {
        cout<<"Match Found";
    }
}
```